# JsonIgnore does not work with Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

How fix this?

I tried to add `@JsonIgnore` to getter, but result was same.

POJO:

```
public class Category {
    // Omitted details

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Category> children;
}
```

From `build.gradle`:

```
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
```

Spring version:

```
4.2.6.RELEASE
```

Context:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You expect GSON to work with a Jackson annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, add `jackson-databind` dependency:

```
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
```

You can remove the `jackson-annotations`, since it will be resolved transitively. Then, with approperaite Jackson jar on the classpath, Spring MVC will automatically configure the required `HttpMessageConverter`s for you. So, there is no need to register them manually. Hence, you can safely get rid of the following:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring usually uses well defined and long names for its abstractions, so you can easily find out what is the purpose of each one. Obviously `GsonHttpMessageConverter` is a `HttpMessageConverter` for [*Gson*](https://github.com/google/gson), not [*Jackson*](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Checkout [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-enable) for more detailed discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at your code:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

You need the `Jackson` Version of the converter